# Does `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` implement `IReadOnlyCollection` or not?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

The question seems simple. Although the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6(v=vs.110).aspx) says it does:

```
public sealed class KeyCollection : ICollection<TKey>, 
    IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>, IEnumerable<TKey>, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

the following code gives an error:

```
class MyKeys<T>
{
    readonly Dictionary<T, T> dict = new Dictionary<T, T> ();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Keys { get { return dict.Keys; } set; }
}
```

saying that there is no conversion from `KeyCollection<T>` to `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Moreover [polish documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/3fcwy8h6(v=vs.110).aspx) (french too for that matter) says it does not:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public sealed class KeyCollection : ICollection<TKey>, 
    IEnumerable<TKey>, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Which is it?

And in case it's the error in english documentation, a bonus question:

Is there a way to get `Keys` as read-only collection?

Comment: While it doesn't implement `IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>` it is read only in that `IsReadOnly` returns true and `Add`, `Remove`, and `Clear` all throw exceptions.

Comment: I always wondered why `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` doesnt implement `ISet<TKey>`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Dictionary.KeyCollection` does not currently implement `IReadOnlyCollection`.

**However**, the interface was added to the next version of .Net (v4.6). You can see that using VS 2015 preview.

You can also see that in [this announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/10/06/announcing-october-2014-updates-to-net-framework-vnext-asp-net-vnext-and-net-native-in-visual-studio-14-ctp4.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) (downloads an excel file with all the changes for v4.6)

Comment: Oh, so maybe the english documentation is up-to-future-date.

Comment: @luk32 If you change the version from 4.5 to anything lower it does show that it doesn't implement `IReadOnlyCollection`

Comment: @luk32 I actually wouldn't be surprised if that's the case (by mistake)

Answer (score 5):

At the time of writing this answer the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,801) did not contain the IReadOnlyCollection interfact implementation:

```
public sealed class KeyCollection: ICollection<TKey>, ICollection
```

Since then, the reference source has been updated to now include the IReadOnlyCollection interface.

```
public sealed class KeyCollection: ICollection<TKey>, ICollection, IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>
```

Comment: Please note that the reference source link above now refers to the updated .NET code where KeyCollection DOES derive from IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the answer to reflect that the reference source now has the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to documentation for .Net framework 4.5. Where it is added. The [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,779) has

```
public sealed class KeyCollection: ICollection<TKey>, ICollection
```

**If** you look at the [**documentation for .Net framework 4.0**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6(v=vs.100).aspx) then it has:

```
public sealed class KeyCollection : ICollection<TKey>, 
    IEnumerable<TKey>, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Where `ICollection<TKey>` [implements](http://May%20be%20a%20mistake%20in%20documentation,%20the%20[original%20source%20code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,779)%20has%20public%20%60sealed%20class%20KeyCollection:%20ICollection%3CTKey%3E,%20ICollection%60%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B) `IEnumerable<T>` and `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable`, so no `IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>` is implemented.

> Is there a way to get Keys as read-only collection?

You can do:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<int> readonlyKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(dictionary.Keys.ToList());
```

Comment: I would say it's *a copy* of `Keys` as a read-only collection, not the original `Keys` wrapped or cast. The original container will be copied. Am I wrong?

Comment: @luk32, yes you are right. If you use Visual studio 2015 and specify .Net framework version .Net 4.6, then you can do `IReadOnlyCollection<int> Keys = dictionary.Keys;`

Comment: For any future readers, please note that the link to the .NET source code in the answer above points to the updated version (4.6) which DOES derive from IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>, but the .NET 4.5 version did not originally include it.